# Adding percentage - need to make into price

Tags: php

I am using the following code to add VAT (20%) on to prices.

```
$VATrate = 20;

echo($row_products['price'] *= (1 + $VATrate / 100));
```

This works well except for when the price has a zero on the end - for example I have an item with ex. VAT price of £249 with VAT added the price is £298.80 - the problem is that the output of that is £249.8 and therefore missing the zero - I don't want to go and add a zero to everything as some prices are £29.95 so do not need a zero on the end.

Is it possible to do this? I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formatting capabilities of [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)...

```
$VATrate = 20;
$total_price = $row_products['price'] *= (1 + $VATrate / 100);
printf("%.2f", $total_price);
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett From the PHP manual: "The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows."

Answer (score 1):

This should be what your looking for :)

```
$number = ($row_products['price'] *= (1 + $VATrate / 100);
$price = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
echo $price;
```

Comment: [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) is better suited here.

Comment: '... The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows ...'

Answer (score 0):

`number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');`